# Is bind peeking disabled on distributed queries?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'm having trouble optimizing an Oracle query after an upgrade to Oracle 11g and this problem is starting to drive me a little mad.

Note, this question has been now fully edited because I have more information after creating a simple test case. The original question is available here: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/12304320/1.

This issue is that when joining two tables, one of which has a `between` condition on a date column, if the query joins to a remote table, bind peeking doesn't happen.

Here is a test case to help reproduce the problem. First set up two source tables. The first is a list of dates, being the first of the month, going back thirty years

```
create table mike_temp_etl_control
as 
select
  add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), 1-row_count) as reporting_date
from (
  select level as row_count
  from dual
  connect by level < 360
);
```

Then some data sourced from `dba_objects`:

```
create table mike_temp_dba_objects as
select owner, object_name, subobject_name, object_id, created
from dba_objects
union all
select owner, object_name, subobject_name, object_id, created
from dba_objects;
```

Then create an empty table to run the data in to:

```
create table mike_temp_1
as
select 
  a.OWNER,
  a.OBJECT_NAME,
  a.SUBOBJECT_NAME,
  a.OBJECT_ID,
  a.CREATED,
  b.REPORTING_DATE
from 
  mike_temp_dba_objects a
  join mike_temp_etl_control b on (
      b.reporting_date between add_months(a.created, -24) and a.created)
  where 1=2;
```

Then run the code. You may need to create a larger version mike_temp_dba_objects to slow the query down (or use some other method to get the execution plan). While the query is running, I get an execution plan from the session by running `select *
from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(sql_id => 'xxxxxxxxxxx'))` from a different session.

```
declare
  pv_report_start_date date := date '2002-01-01';
  v_report_end_date date := date '2012-07-01';

begin

  INSERT /*+ APPEND */
  INTO mike_temp_5
  select 
    a.OWNER,
    a.OBJECT_NAME,
    a.SUBOBJECT_NAME,
    a.OBJECT_ID,
    a.CREATED,
    b.REPORTING_DATE
from 
  mike_temp_dba_objects a
  join mike_temp_etl_control b on (
    b.reporting_date between add_months(a.created, -24) and a.created)
  cross join dual@emirrl -- This line causes problems...
where 
  b.reporting_date between add_months(pv_report_start_date, -12) and v_report_end_date;

  rollback;  
end;
```

By having a remote table in the query, the cardinality estimate for the mike_temp_etl_control table is completely wrong and bind peeking doesn't seem to be happening.

The execution plan for the query above is shown below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                | Name                  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | INSERT STATEMENT         |                       |       |       |   373 (100)|
|   1 |  LOAD AS SELECT          |                       |       |       |            |
|*  2 |   FILTER                 |                       |       |       |            |
|   3 |    MERGE JOIN            |                       |     5 |   655 |   373  (21)|
|   4 |     SORT JOIN            |                       |  1096 |   130K|   370  (20)|
|   5 |      MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN|                       |  1096 |   130K|   369  (20)|
|   6 |       REMOTE             | DUAL                  |     1 |       |     2   (0)|
|   7 |       BUFFER SORT        |                       |  1096 |   130K|   367  (20)|
|*  8 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL | MIKE_TEMP_DBA_OBJECTS |  1096 |   130K|   367  (20)|
|*  9 |     FILTER               |                       |       |       |            |
|* 10 |      SORT JOIN           |                       |     2 |    18 |     3  (34)|
|* 11 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL  | MIKE_TEMP_ETL_CONTROL |     2 |    18 |     2   (0)|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If I then replace the remote `dual` with the local version I get the correct cardinality (139 instead of 2):

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation              | Name                  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | INSERT STATEMENT       |                       |       |       | 10682 (100)|
|   1 |  LOAD AS SELECT        |                       |       |       |            |
|*  2 |   FILTER               |                       |       |       |            |
|   3 |    MERGE JOIN          |                       |   152K|    19M| 10682   (3)|
|   4 |     SORT JOIN          |                       |   438K|    51M| 10632   (2)|
|   5 |      NESTED LOOPS      |                       |   438K|    51M|   369  (20)|
|   6 |       FAST DUAL        |                       |     1 |       |     2   (0)|
|*  7 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL| MIKE_TEMP_DBA_OBJECTS |   438K|    51M|   367  (20)|
|*  8 |     FILTER             |                       |       |       |            |
|*  9 |      SORT JOIN         |                       |   139 |  1251 |     3  (34)|
|* 10 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL| MIKE_TEMP_ETL_CONTROL |   139 |  1251 |     2   (0)|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So, I guess the question is how can I get the correct cardinality to be estimated? Is this an Oracle bug or is this the expected behaviour?

Comment: To get rid of the easy stuff have you re-gathered [statistics](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/general002.htm#ADMIN11525) on the table?

Comment: Yes, the statistics should all be fresh. Will double check that tomorrow though. It's part of a data warehouse ETL load, with stats gathered on everything as it goes

Comment: I know there was a bug in versions > 11.1 that had a work-a-round which included setting the "_optim_peek_user_binds" parameter to false. This can effect the optimizer but I don't know exactly how. You can check whether this parameter is set to true or false, it should be true for maximum performance. The bug causes ORA-3137 errors.

Comment: @Gisli I probably want to opposite of _optim_peek_user_binds = false, since it seems not to be peeking. In one of the trace files I created that parameter came out and was set to true. Plus I'm not getting the error.

Comment: I've talked to my DBA (although I'm waiting to hear anything back) and am starting to think it might be a bug... especially given the lack of answers coming though.

Comment: Do you have a histogram on one of the columns with a bind variable?  That is required to use adaptive cursor sharing, which may fix this issue.  Also, how many bind variables do you have?  Adaptive cursor sharing does not work if you have more than 14: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16638/optimops.htm#CIHIGAHB

Answer (score 1):

I think you should mess about dynamic sampling. It works in 11g differently so may it is the reason of your troubles.